# Aligning to left of right in linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set one textview to the left and the other to the right in a horizontal linearlayout, which is nested in a vertical linearlayout nested in a scrollview. The horizontal linearlayout looks like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >   
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Type of Event: "
    style="@style/black_text_bold"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/outputType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Loading..."
    style="@style/black_text"
    android:visibility="gone"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

How would I go about aligning this? I want txttype to start on the left and outputtype to end on the right like:

```
|                           |
| txtType:       outputType |
|                           |
```

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Comment: use layou_weights in the textviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this..

```
    <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
         >   
     <TextView android:id="@+id/txtType"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Type of Event: "
       style="@style/black_text_bold"
       android:visibility="gone"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/outputType"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/black_text"
        android:visibility="gone"/>    
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use a `RelativeLayout` and use attributes `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight` like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >   
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Type of Event: "
    style="@style/black_text_bold"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/outputType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    style="@style/black_text"
    android:visibility="gone"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity) attribute to set how a child should be positioned in its container.

Your left view's `layout_gravity` should be `left` to align it to the container's left edge. And similarly for the right view - `layout_gravity` `right` to align it to the container's right edge.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtType"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
       android:layout_width="1"
       android:text="Type of Event: "
       style="@style/black_text_bold"
       android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/outputType"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
       android:layout_width="1"
       android:text="Loading..."
       style="@style/black_text"
       android:visibility="gone"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **TextView** xml with id **android:id="@+id/outputType"**, change** android:layout_width="wrap_content"** with **android:layout_width="0dip"** and set **android:layout_weight="1"**. These change will help you to get your result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtType"
        style="@style/black_text_bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Type of Event: "
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputType"
        style="@style/black_text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```